# Calculate center point of spherical octant

Tags: geometry, spheres, spherical-geometry

If I had a sphere and an octant like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hui_Zheng25/publication/10745241/figure/fig2/AS:281378278133762@1444097217358/Surface-discretization-of-one-octant-of-a-sphere-using-3-curvilinear-quadrilateral.png), how would I find point $P$?

I can already calculate the other portions of the sphere using the parametric form equations, but I am unsure how I would combine to arrive at the $(x, y, z)$ of $P$ in the image.

For clarification in the image:

$O$ is the center of the sphere; it is not necessarily the origin of the space

Points $A, B, C, D, E, F$ are already known

Point $P$ is a point on the *surface* of the octant

I would've though that $P$ would've been the center of the arc from $B$ to $F$ in a similar fashion that $C$ is from $E$ to $F$.

A close approximation of this is to take the inital center point $(x, y, z)$ and make $P = (x + \epsilon/\sqrt{3}, y + \epsilon/\sqrt{3}, z + \epsilon/\sqrt{3}$) though I believe this to be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're asking for a point *on* the sphere.

By symmetry $x = y = z$.  And given that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = e = 3 x^2$, we immediately find that $x = y = z = \sqrt{e/3}$.

[image: Point on sphere]

Comment: So the position would be $p = \epsilon/\sqrt{3}$; $(x + p, y + p, z + p)$?

Comment: Yes.  (Though I was assuming that $p = (0,0,0)$.)

Comment: Sure, fair assumption; need to implement so that initial $(x, y, z)$ is arbitrary with some radius $\epsilon$ such that I can compute the center of the 8 octants.

Comment: This actually gives me the centroid of the octant, not the point on the surface

Comment: Please re-state your question clearly and unambiguously.  What is "center point"?  Is point $p$ on the surface of the sphere?  (yes or no)  Is the radius of the sphere $1$ or $e$?  When you say "octant", everyone understands the octant is defined by the origin $(0,0,0$ and three axes.

Comment: Yes $P$ is on the surface. The radius is represented by $\epsilon$ and can be any number dependent upon the problem (other than $0$). I've updated my OP.

Comment: I also cannot view `imgur` links on this system due to security implementations.